# android application launching issue

Tags: android

I am new in android. I am trying to learn Android. For that my intention is to run hello world application in emulator. But during running the application, in console I am getting the following issue:

```
[2012-06-22 13:07:01 - hello] ------------------------------
[2012-06-22 13:07:01 - hello] Android Launch!
[2012-06-22 13:07:01 - hello] adb is running normally.
[2012-06-22 13:07:01 - hello] Could not find hello.apk!
```

Please help to fix this error.

Comment: Did you tried with clean that project? And, try to remove that project and restore it from local history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time the apk is not create. Try this way.

Go your Eclipse Project menu then clear option and select the project then run again. it help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The APK is not Create, Please Go to your Eclipse Menu and Click on Click option and now select your Project and  Click on ok Button

or

you can select build automatically function also.

Comment: I have reinstalled some APIs and again trying to run my hello world application. But now getting different error:Error generating final archive: Unable to get debug signature key